# What does kmax and ks in train.kknn refer to?

Tags: r

Can someone explain to me how train.kknn works? In particular, I am wondering what kmax and ks are? Are they referring to the k of the nearest neighbor model? Or are they referring to the k of k-folds?

I looked up the documentation but did not find anything more specific (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kknn/kknn.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**what kmax and ks are?**

kmax is the maximum number of k that you want to test. For example, if you set kmax = 11, train.kknn will try all values of k from 1 to 11 and choose the one that gives the best performance.

ks is a vector that specifies the exact values of k that you want to test. For example, if you set ks = c(3, 5, 7), train.kknn will only try these three values of k and choose the best one.

**Are they referring to the k of the nearest neighbor model? Or are they referring to the k of k-folds?**

You can specify some parameters when you use train.kknn, such as kmax and ks. They both refer to the k of the nearest neighbor model, not the k of k-folds.

You can examine the examples in the link below;

[Train.kkn RDRR](https://rdrr.io/cran/kknn/man/train.kknn.html)

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask, from my understanding, cross-validation produces k models, where each model correspond to each of the k folds. But how does cv.kknn or training.kknn pick the final or best model? What is this final model? For example, if I were to split my data into a training and test set, then perform cross-validation using knn on the training set, would the final/best model refer to the model with the best value of say k (i.e., the k of knn?), or does cv.kknn automatically picks it for us?

Comment: If you think of it as a metaphor like;

kNN finds k closest friends based on similarity. cv.kknn tests one k, distance, and weight. train.kknn tries many and picks the best. 

[k-fold-cross-validation-for-knn](https://www.kaggle.com/code/parthshah98/k-fold-cross-validation-for-knn)

[k-nearest-neighbor-classification](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/k-nearest-neighbor-classification-scikit-learn)

[choosing-optimal-k-for-knn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126051/choosing-optimal-k-for-knn)